# Why is there a six character minimum on edits?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Quite often, I'll want to make a change to a post that's under 6 characters. Sometimes it's for a grammar niggle (e.g. i instead of I, Im instead of I'm), but sometimes it's to actually correct some code in an answer - recently, an answer to one of my questions was perfect except for a missing $ in front of a string; it would have been handy if I could have fixed that myself.

I assume the six character minimum is to stop people gaming reputation, but perhaps smaller edits could be allowed for no gain?

Comment: [***The best answer ever!!! :-)***](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82535)